# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hi below is my JSON String

```
{
  "addons": {
    "BANDWIDTH": [
      [
        "HSV-A1ABW-C",
        "BANDWIDTH",
        "vCloud Air",
        {
          "Monthly": {
            "1_99999": [
              "219.00",
              "HSV-A1ABW-12MT0-C1S",
              "vCloud Air - 12 monthly Payments"
            ]
          },
          "Prepaid": {
            "1_99999": [
              "2577.00",
              "HSV-A1ABW-12PT0-C1S",
              "vCloud Air - Internet Bandwidth Subscription - 12 month Prepaid"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}

public class sample
{
   @JsonProperty("addons")
    public Addons addons;
   //getters and setters
}
 public class Addons
{
   @JsonProperty("BANDWIDTH")
    public List<List<String>> bANDWIDTH;
    //getters and setters
}


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();     
obj = objectMapper.readValue(json,sample.getClass());
```

when i run the , i am getting the following error 
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
here i have array has an array and in that array have an object along with values , how to parse this using jackson and java. Please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have declared BANDWIDTH to be of type List<List<String>> , while in your JSON it is a mixed list of 3 strings:

```
"HSV-A1ABW-C",
"BANDWIDTH",
"vCloud Air"
```

and a complex object:

```
{
    "Monthly": {
        "1_99999": [
        "219.00",
        "HSV-A1ABW-12MT0-C1S",
        "vCloud Air - 12 monthly Payments"
        ]
    },
    "Prepaid": {
        "1_99999": [
        "2577.00",
        "HSV-A1ABW-12PT0-C1S",
        "vCloud Air - Internet Bandwidth Subscription - 12 month Prepaid"
        ]
    }
}
```

hence the error

And easiest "workaround" you can employ, is to just declare you *BANDWIDTH* property to be of type:

```
List<List<Object>>
```

and let Jackson deserialize it as a combination of Maps and Lists.

Comment: hi thanks  for your reply. how to get data from from this 
{Monthly={1_5=[230.00, HSV-A1AST-12MT1-C2S, VMware vCloud Air],6_11=[219.00, HSV-A1AST-12MT2-C2S, VMware vCloud Air],Prepaid={1_5=[2707.00, HSV-A1AST-12PT1-C1S, VMware vCloud Air], 6_11=[2572.00, HSV-A1AST-12PT2-C1S, VMware vCloud Air]}

Comment: The simplest option you have is to deserialize your data as `List<List<Object>>`, this way `{ "Monthly": { ... } "Prepaid" { ....}` JSON-object will be converted into _java.util.Map_ with more _Maps_ and String _Lists_ inside it, which you can then process in the Java code.

Another option would be to create a Java class to represent this 'Monthly/Prepaid' object, and use a custom Jackson deserializer to parse it. You may also try to utilize the polymorphic deserialization features of Jackson, however it could be a hard nut to crack, with the structure you have.